# Activity para llamadas en Flutter

Tags: flutter

Soy nuevo en Flutter y preciso mandar a llamar el activity de llamadas que trae uno en el teléfono luego de presionar un ícono. Allí coloco el método que debería mandar a llamar a ese activity. Pero como es fuera de la App no se como se hace. Agradecería su ayuda.

```
onPressed: () { Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => Llamada()));},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso necesitas llamar a código nativo por medio de Platform Channels, o simplemente usar packages que ya existen.

Como los siguientes:

- https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
- https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent
- https://pub.dev/packages/intent

Te recomiendo el primero, que es creado por google.

Lo usarías de la siguiente forma:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'tel:+155501099';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: Me da problema con la última versión de url_launcher que existe. Instalé una más antigua y me funciona con tu forma. Te lo agradezco. Para que funcione en IOS; ¿Que tendría que hacer?

Comment: el ejemplo que puse debería funcionar en iOS, revisa la documentación del package

Comment: Perfecto, dice que si funciona en IOS. Muchas gracias nuevamente Diego por echarme el cable. Un saludo

Comment: dale, no hay de que, estamos para aprender,  te recomiendo un canal de youtube que tengo con un amigo de mexico, sobre Flutter/Dart en español :  https://www.youtube.com/c/TheDartSide

Comment: Te has ganado un nuevo subscriptor